# Gtk is licenced under GPL and Gtkmm is under LGPL, but Gtkmm links with Gtk，am I allowed to relese my app without opensourcing it when I use Gtkmm?

Tags: gtk, licensing, gtkmm

`Gtk` is licensed under GPL and `Gtkmm` is under LGPL, but Gtkmm links with
Gtk.
am I allowed to relese my app without opensourcing it when I use Gtkmm only?

Comment: This is a legal question, not a software development question, therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please see the [licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/licensing/info) tag for guidance.

Answer (score 4):

GTK is not released under the GPL.

GTK is licensed under the terms of the GNU Library General Public License, version 2.0 or, at your option, any later version as released by the Free Software Foundation.

See the [`COPYING` file in the GTK source code repository](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/COPYING).

Answer (score 1):

From [Gtkmm's license page](https://gtkmm.org/en/license.html) (my emphasis):

> gtkmm is licensed under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL)
> for all platforms. Our intent in licensing it in this way is to
> provide it for use through shared libraries in all projects both open
> and proprietary. Other GNU projects may of course integrate and link
> in a static manner. The full body of the license is provided for your
> inspection.
>
> This is the only license which grants you use of the software, so if
> you do not agree to its terms, you may not use this software.
>
> **Note that this license does not require you to release the source code
> of your own applications or libraries and does not require you to pay
> any fees.**

So it seems you can!